# rgeClass auth does not exist

Tags: laravel

I just migrated from Laravel 5.3 to 5.4.

In local, it is just working fine. I did a "composer update" and everything works.

So, I merged to master, and when trying to install new libs with "composer install",

I have a

```
  PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught ReflectionException: Class auth does not exist in /home/forge/my.kendozone.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:681
 Stack trace:
 #0 /home/forge/my.kendozone.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(681): ReflectionClass->__construct('auth')
 #1 /home/forge/my.kendozone.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(565): Illuminate\Container\Container->build('auth')
 #2 /home/forge/my.kendozone.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(702): Illuminate\Container\Container->make('auth')
 #3 /home/forge/my.kendozone.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(1070): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->make('auth')
 #4 /home/forge/my.kendozone.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php(159): Illuminate\Container\Container->offsetGet('auth')
 #5 /home/forge/my.kendozone.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php(128): Illumin in /home/forge/my.kendozone.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/     Illuminate/Container/Container.php on line 681
 PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught ReflectionException: Class auth does not exist in /home/forge/my.kendozone.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:681
 Stack trace:
 #0 /home/forge/my.kendozone.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(681): ReflectionClass->__construct('auth')
 #1 /home/forge/my.kendozone.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(565): Illuminate\Container\Container->build('auth')
 #2 /home/forge/my.kendozone.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(702): Illuminate\Container\Container->make('auth')
 #3 /home/forge/my.kendozone.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(1070): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->make('auth')
 #4 /home/forge/my.kendozone.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php(159): Illuminate\Container\Container->offsetGet('auth')
 #5 /home/forge/my.kendozone.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php(128): Illumin in /home/forge/my.kendozone.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/.     Illuminate/Container/Container.php on line 681
```

In general, when this poor message appears, it means that there is a problem with one of my config files, but here, all my files work great in local, so, I don't know where to look for....

I tried to comment each provider of config/app.php, but also didn't work.

I try to revert composer.json to the previous version, but still the same error....

Any idea to get me out of this issue, my productive app is Down :(

Comment: Have you tried to clear the configuration in product ? `php artisan config:cache`;

Comment: On a side note, it's always good to have a environment server to test stuff online before moving to production.

Comment: my issue is that no php artisan commands will respond, all fail

Comment: I tried composer dump-autoload

Comment: Wow, I recommend quickly reverting your production with version control... while you are looking for the solution.

Comment: I'm stuck in that step, I can't find the commit where I merge my branch

Comment: ok I could switch branch to the latest working one. Now, my site works. But now, I don't know how to clean master